# Write a recursive C++ function that computes and returns the product of the integers in an array

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int theProduct(int anArray[], int n);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    int myArray[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    cout << "The product of the array elements of myArray is "<<theProduct(myArray,3)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int theProduct(int anArray[], int n)
{

    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    else if (n == 1)  //base case
        return anArray[0] * anArray[1];
    else
        return anArray[n] * theProduct(anArray, n - 1);

}
```

I expected my output to be 6, instead my output is "The product of the array elements of myArray is 1048565344" 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your array elements are myArray [0], myArray [1], myArray [2]. But not myArray [3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use `anArray[n-1]` instead of `anArray[n]` because 3rd element has the index 3-1=2.
2. Don't return `anArray[0] * anArray[1]` but `anArray[0]` because you already multipliyed with `anArray[1]`

That's your code with the changes (and some more smaller ones):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int theProduct(int anArray[], int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        return 0;
    else if (size == 1)  // base case
        return anArray[0];
    else
        return anArray[size - 1] * theProduct(anArray, size - 1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int myArray[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    cout << "The product of the array elements of myArray is "
         << theProduct(myArray,3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the size is `1` you just have one element, therefore in

```
else if (n == 1)  //base case
    return anArray[0] * anArray[1];
```

you are actually going out of the bounds by accessing `anArray[1]`.

In:

```
else
    return anArray[n] * theProduct(anArray, n - 1);
```

if the size is `n` you cannot access `anArray[n]` because the elements are counted from `0` to `n-1`. For example, in your array the size is `3` but the elements have indexes: `0, 1, 2`.

What you meant is this:

```
int theProduct(int anArray[], int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return anArray[0];
    else
        return anArray[n-1] * theProduct(anArray, n - 1);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94e780a2c2a96ff8)

which correctly outputs `6`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this should work well. You should invoke the function with the max index of the array:

cout << "The product of the array elements of myArray is " << theProduct(myArray,2) << endl;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative version that uses a helper function and a recursive function that recursively splits the array into two parts. It will use log2(n) levels of recursion instead of n levels of recursion reducing stack overhead.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int Product(int A[], size_t n);
int ProductR(int A[], size_t low, size_t end);

int main(int Argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    cout << "The product of the array elements of myArray is " <<
            Product(A, sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int Product(int A[], size_t n)
{
    return ProductR(A, 0, n);
}

int ProductR(int A[], size_t low, size_t end)
{
    if((end - low) == 0)
        return 1;
    if((end - low) == 1)
        return A[low];
    size_t mid = (low + end)/2;
    return ProductR(A, low, mid) * ProductR(A, mid, end);
}
```